# How do I connect multiple subnets together?

Tags: windows, routing

I am not a networks expert, I have a basic knowledge of networking.

In my workplace I have 3 dsl routers with different subnets (192.168.0.0, 192.168.1.0, 192.168.2.0). They are connected to a LAYER-2 SMC-EZ6516TX along with a NAS (D-Link Sharecenter connected at 192.168.1.150).

How can I connect the subnets together so that I can see the NAS in all subnets and have each of the subnets have a DHCP service for their pcs?

Any direction would be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

You would need to have a netmask of 255.255.0.0 on your PC that's trying to access the NAS. This way you will be able to see all the devices from 192.168.x.x subnets.

Then to have DHCP pools for each subnet, these would need to be on separate VLANs, otherwise I do not see it working out. You would just get DHCP service conflicts on the network and you need to separate the traffic. I am not familiar with the switch you are using, so not sure whether it supports VLANs.

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect. The OP merely needs to set up and configure routing between the subnets in order for computers on each of them to reach the NAS. Configuring the subnet mask as 255.255.0.0 would put all of the computers (and the routers) in the same subnet, which would defeat the purpose of having separate subnets.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Unless... it's just the one PC/Server that needs to access this NAS.

Comment: No, I just want seperate networks for each department, but every network to be able to access the nas and or printers. I decided to make a linux box which will have a connection to all 3 networks through eth0 and will have nfs mounted the nas there (the nas can become an nfsmount point) so all the users will see the linux box as nas/printserver

Comment: This is so wrong. Without a gateway and appropriate routing tables, the other network segments will have no idea how to get to the NAS. And as for the DHCP part, that is one way of doing it, but if these are genuinely seperate networks, then you shouldn't need to segregate them with vlans as they're already segregated by a router.